# What is this 3d design of Bitcoin?

Tags: wallet, development, services, bitcoin-logo

Lots of places online have a ray-traced, photorealistic image of an elaborate Bitcoin mint of the same design:
https://www.insiderfinancial.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Two-Bitcoins.png

What is that design? where can i get a 3D model of it or a heightmap image of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's a rendering. I think that's an actual copper coin with a bitcoin/circuitry theme.

Googling the text on the back, "AOCS APPROVED MJB 2013," finds [this site](http://www.jezuss.nl/bi/bitcoin.htm), which gives the designer's name, Mick Bruce. Presumably "MJB" is his initials.

Googling that turns up [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63259.msg739922#msg739922) on BitcoinTalk, which is pretty similar to your coin.

I can't turn up a 3d model, but the designer, Mick Bruce, might have it. You might be able to contact him via the email in [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=23256.0), or by [this onename](https://onename.com/bitcoinfridge).

Comment: There's now a free 3d version here https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2724795

Answer (score 1):

They sell the 3D models all over the internet. I have dozens of multiple designs, including MJB Copper and the one with the pick-axe on the back (my favorite).

Comment: Someone has copied a pretty good free version on thingiverse: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2724795